# Shortcut for: $foo = explode(" ", "bla ble bli"); echo $foo[0]

Tags: php, shortcut, explode

is there a way to get the n-th element of a splitted string without using a variable?

My PHP code always looks like this:

```
$foo = explode(" ", "bla ble bli");
echo $foo[0];
```

Is there a shorter way maybe like in Python?

```
print "bla ble bli".split(" ")[0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what people should be using instead of `explode` most of the time:

```
$foo = strtok("bla ble bli", " ");
```

It cuts off the first string part until the first `" "`.

If you can't let go of explode, then the closest idiom to accomplish `[0]` like in Python is:

```
$foo = current(explode(...));
```

If it's not just the first element, then it becomes a tad more cumbersome:

```
$foo = current(array_slice(explode(...), 2));   // element [2]
```

Comment: How does this answer the question *is there a way to get the n-th element* ? I mean you can call `strtok` in a loop, but then `explode` and array access seems to be easier...

Comment: The "good" answer is `echo current(explode(' ', 'a b c'));`. But only works for the first one.

Comment: @FelixKling: Right. Sorry. Only read the first part. It's more syntactic salt if you want `[n]`

Comment: I agree with you that there are way better methods for getting the first element of a splitted string but that's not exactly what I was looking for. Is thought of a way to get the n-th element not only the first one.

Comment: @KebdnK: See update. That's more function calls in PHP. Or you just wait a few years until PHP 5.4 comes out, then array dereferences will work in PHP as you are used to from other languages. (But "wait a few years" is not a good answer.)

Comment: @mario: Thank you for the update. It works but it just doesn't look so elegant because of the three funcion calls.
So for an elegant solution we have to wait a few years, I think.

Comment: @KebdnK: It's not only bad on the eyes, but also hard to remember at times. That's why I also see many people define an array dereferencing utility function for the time being. Something like `d($expr, 2)` is the optimum you can achieve with current PHP.

Comment: @KebdnK what is stopping you from putting the three function calls into its own function or method? anything you have to repeat, or is hard to read should probably be put into its own well-named function or method.

Comment: How on earth is this a **shortcut**?

Comment: @salathe: No temporary variables, no splitting up into two expression. Shortcut does not necessarily mean less typing. :/

Comment: But a shortcut does need the path to be shorter; calling two functions looks, to me, to be the longer route.

Comment: @salathe: Well why, yes. You're right. But see Pascals answer. We'll have to wait quite a while to be able to use the short version. Meanwhile this lengthy workaround is the idiomatic and functional approach to achieve what other languages can. But as said, the strtok() call is the common case anyway. (Most people neglect to pick the shortest path there.)

Comment: +1 I knew about `strtok` before, but never thought about using it for this.

Comment: @nikic: Neither did I until I've read it somewhere. It's simply not originally purposed and named perceptibly for that.

Comment: @mario: Yep. All those functions copied directly from C with ugly names like `strtok`, `strpbrk` or `strcspn` get overlooked quickly.

Answer (score 2):

*(Not really an answer per se -- others did answer pretty well)*

This is one of the features that should arrive with one of the next versions of PHP *(PHP 5.4, maybe)*.

For more informations, see [**Features in PHP trunk: Array dereferencing**](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html) -- quoting one of the given examples :

```
<?php
function foo() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
echo foo()[2]; // prints 3
?>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Can't wait to install PHP 5.4 (if it ships with this release) ;-)

Comment: Many people are waiting for this *(it's a recurring feature request)* ; no idea when PHP 5.4 will be released, though -- if that feature even makes it into the next version of PHP ; and if that next version is even called 5.4 ^^

Answer (score 1):

try this:

its one line:

```
<?php

echo (($f=explode(" ", "bla ble bli"))?$f[0]:'');

?>
```

result here:
http://codepad.org/tnhbpYdd

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
function splode($string, $delimiter, $index){
 $r = explode($delimiter, $string);
 return $r[$index];
}
```

I use like a hojillion little functions like this.

Comment: oh, it exists.  i use it for all my internal projects where nobody will ever need to know about my spaghetti code and other horrible syntactical issues.

Answer (score 0):

With only one expression I can think of:

```
echo list($a) = explode(' ', 'a b c') ? $a : '';
echo list($_, $b) = explode(' ', 'a b c') ? $b : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know although you could define a function and use that.

```
function firstWord($string) {
  $foo = explode(" ", $string);
  return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do what you want, even though I've wanted to do the same thing many times before. For that specific case you could do

```
$bar = substr($foo, 0, strpos($foo, " "));
```

which stops there being one extra variable, but isn't exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably the cleanest way I can think of doing what OP has requested.  It defines a function, but no variables of it's own and it'll get the job done for just about any situation:

`function at(&$arr, &$pos) { return $arr[$pos]; }`

Example usage:

`echo at( explode('|', 'a|b|c|d'), 1 );    // Outputs 'b'`

The function is a single line of code and wouldn't be hard to commit to memory.  If you're only using it once, you can define it in the local scope of where it'll be used to minimize code clutter.
As a slight added benefit, because the function does no checks on `$arr` or `$pos`, it'll throw all the same errors that it would if you tried to access a non-existent index for an array, or will even return the individual characters in a string or items in a key-value paired array.

Answer (score 0):

close. the right track is making a function or method for something that gets repeated.

```
function extract_word($input, $index) {
    $input = explode(' ', $input);
    return $input[$index];
}
```

add a third argument of $separater = ' ' if you may have different word separaters.