# Why can't I use an array index on the return value of a function?

Tags: php, language-design, language-features

Why can't I do this?

```
explode(',','1,2,3', 1)[0]
```

Every other language supports it.

**Answers I'm looking for:** (since people seem to think this is a pointless rant)

Is there some sort of a difference between how a variable and a return value behaves that I should be made aware of?

Was this a design decision? Were they just lazy? Is there something about the way the language was built that makes this exceedingly difficult to implement?

Comment: Because it's not supported by the language parser. PHP 5.4 might add it. -- Until then, there are [a few fiddly workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491885/shortcut-for-foo-explode-bla-ble-bli-echo-foo0/5491911#5491911).

Comment: "Every other language", eh? Anyway, this "question" really just amounts to a rant. You know it's not possible, so there's no useful answer to this question.

Comment: @Tomalak: Not really. There could be a fundamental misunderstanding I have about PHP and how it works. For example, it could be returning something other than what I expect; there could be some difference between how a variable behaves and how a return value behaves.

Comment: it does not seem so badly a rant imo. This could be a nice feature if it will get implemented in a newer version of PHP. Same for `(new Obj())->method();`

Comment: I would add a 'design' tag to this question, since it is as much about the design of programming languages as it is about php.  There is probably some design decision that led the authors to not include this feature, and that is what the question is asking for.  Fair question.

Comment: @Mark: You have since improved the question, which was going to be my next suggestion.

Comment: This question was edited to provide clarification so earlier close votes may no longer be warranted (including mine). I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

> Why can't I do this?

Because PHP doesn't currently support this syntax. But you can pass it to a function, e.g.:

```
current(explode(',','1,2,3', 1));
```

Otherwise, you have to assign the return value to a variable first, then access via index.

**More Info**:

> So one can chain method calls or
>   property access. Now for a long time
>   people requested the same thing for
>   array offset access. **This was often
>   rejected due to uncertainties about
>   memory issues**, as we don't like
>   memory leaks. But after proper
>   evaluation Felipe committed the patch
>   which allows you to do things like:

```
function foo() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
echo foo()[2]; // prints 3
```

http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html

So, it is in the development pipeline but, as I stated, is not currently supported.

### Update

PHP >= 5.4 [now supports](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) function array dereferencing, e.g. `foo()[0]`

Comment: Explain the downvote. The answer is correct: "PHP doesn't currently support this syntax."

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but... "doesn't support it" wasn't really the answer I was looking for. *Why?* Was this a design decision? Were they just lazy? Is there something about the way the language was built that makes this exceeding difficult to implement?

Comment: Very well. I'll add more info.

Comment: Just do http://stackoverflow.com/a/13113/632951

Answer (score 2):

In my framework I wrote a function to be able to do it with all possiible array:

```
function elem($array,$key) {
  return $array[$key];
}

//> usage 
echo elem($whateverArrayHere,'key');
echo elem(explode(),1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode return an array, not reference.

```
$tab = explode (',','1,2,3', 1);
$tab[0] = ','
```

Comment: I don't understand... arrays support the `[]` syntax, so why shouldn't this?

Comment: Even if it returned a reference, the syntax is still not supported. Reference has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I think php say, $tab it's not yet a array

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider....

```
  list($value_I_want_to_keep)=explode(',','1,2,3', 1);
```

or

```
  $value_I_want_to_keep=strtok('1,2,3',',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pieces = explode(',','1,2,3', 1);
```

Use the first index with:

```
$pieces[0];
```

Comment: Yes...I wasn't asking for a workaround, just wondering why it's not supported.