# Is there a function()[key] similar syntax for PHP?

Tags: php

I always loved how i can quickly do with JavaScript:

```
function hello(){
  return ['foo', 'bar'];
}

hello()[0]; // foo
```

Why can't we do such things with PHP or is there another short syntax for that?

Comment: It's possible starting from PHP 5.4. (See http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html or search for "array dereferencing"). There are numerous wrapper functions to use in the meantime. Possible duplicate of [Shortcut for: $foo = explode(" ", "bla ble bli"); echo $foo\[0\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491885/shortcut-for-foo-explode-bla-ble-bli-echo-foo0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's just plain not possible to access unnamed array or string by index in php.

Answer (score 1):

If the size is fixed:

```
function returnTwoVars() {
    ....
    return array( $var1, $var2 );
}

list( $var1, $var2 ) = returnTwoVars();
```