# Explode, Array Access and PHP Syntax

Tags: php, syntax, explode

Just wondering why this syntax is not working in PHP? What workaround do most people use - if you want to write concise one-liner code?

```
$str = explode(" ", "foo bar")[0];
// thought $str would be $foo. instead I get error.
// guess I hadn't noticed this issue before.
```

Comment: That's called _array dereferencing_, and it will be available in PHP5.4 (currently in beta). It doesn't work in PHP 5.3 or earlier though.

Comment: @Michael: I think your comment should be the answer to this question.

Comment: It's buried somewhere in the changelog: http://www.php.net/releases/NEWS_5_4_0_beta2.txt

Comment: I, for one, can't wait for this feature to arrive and become widely supported as servers get upgraded.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result) or in this particular case [Shortcut for: $foo = explode(“ ”, “bla ble bli”); echo $foo(0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491885/shortcut-for-foo-explode-bla-ble-bli-echo-foo0)

Comment: @Nicolás Only if I can't find a duplicate. I know it's been asked before.

Comment: @Michael: Last week, I was tempted to install a rogue `php-cgi` in my `/cgi-bin/` just for that very reason. ha

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not chainable, meaning you cannot combine the `explode` function with an accessor, such as `[0]`. What you want to do is:

```
$arr = explode(" ", "foo bar");
$str = $arr[0];
```

"Chainable" may not be the right word, but either way, you can't combine functions like that.

Comment: Agreed.  Complex one liners are almost always predicated on an unintended behavior of the code.  This behavior can change undocumented in a bugfix patch and can even be inconsistent against runtimes. PHP can optimize out whitespace no problem. Optimizing it for a developer to read is much better.

Answer (score 2):

As people have said, it can't be done like that.  If you really, *really* want to do it in one line, you can use a ternary statement.

```
$str = ($tmp=explode(" ", "foo bar")) ? $tmp[0] : '';
echo $str; // "foo"
```

### Update:

This can look 'less ugly' if you wrap that into a function.

```
function single_explode($delim, $str, $index) {
    return ($tmp=explode($delim, $str)) ? $tmp[$index] : '';
}

$str = single_explode(" ", "foo bar", 0);

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

A additional method is use `array_shift`, that discard the first element of array and return it.

```
<?php
    echo array_shift(explode(" ", "foo bar")); // === foo
?>
```

See this [full example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PN1zyJ). Don't use it on strict mode.

Comment: You could use `current()` without any warning. (Cause that's a language construct, not a function.)

Comment: @mario Great! I never used `current()` function, but now I know that is very useful for that.