# Is there a way to return an array key from a function in one line?

Tags: php

For example:

```
$str = 'one-two-three';

$one = explode('-', $str);
```

Is there a way to make $one equal to "one" without doing `$one = $one[0]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut for: $foo = explode(" ", "bla ble bli"); echo $foo\[0\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491885/shortcut-for-foo-explode-bla-ble-bli-echo-foo0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use [`list()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($one,$two,$three) = explode('-', $str);
echo $one;
// one
```

`list()` for multi-assignment isn't quite as nice as being able to dereference an array element directly from a function call, or as convenient as Python's multi-assignment, but it does the job.

In PHP 5.4, we'll be able to dereference directly from the function call, as in:

```
// Coming in 5.4...
explode("-", $str)[0]
```

Comment: +1 For array dereferencing! Not gonna lie ... I'm pretty stoked about this

Comment: Silly me, I forgot about list(). :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the right function for the job:

```
 $one = strtok($str, "-");
```

See [`strtok()`](http://php.net/strtok) or [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) with third parameter.

Comment: I just used that as a (perhaps bad) quick example. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
list($one, $two, $three) = explode('-', $str);
```

or

```
foreach($one as $number) {
    $$number = $number;
}
```

for a larger array...